# Why are all my brushes black when I test the level I built with Hammer?

Tags: hammer

In Valve's map-making tool Hammer, I have created several brushes which I use as walls, ceilings, and floors. I've added textures to them, and I have a light entity on the ceiling. all the props and entities in the game are textured and visible.

Unfortunately, when I try to play the map, all the brushes are black. There are no textures or colors besides black on the brushes.

What could be causing this issue? I have tried compiling the map with HDR off, and HDR on, but receive the same effect.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at some examples from the maps that come with the editor. Compare them with what you have and see what's different.

Comment: Missing light source?

Comment: @Byte56 I have tried that, but to no avail. Actually, when building the map, I followed the official tutorial, but this error still occurred. It seems a few others on the internets have this issue, but the fixes that worked for them didn't work for me.

Comment: @Stephen I have a light source, as said in my question.

Comment: Maybe the light sources are layered. Like `LightB` only affects `LayerB` and you need to make sure your brushes are in the same layer as your light. Just a wild guess.

Comment: @Byte56 Thanks. How would one go about doing that, thought? This is my first time using Hammer :P

Comment: As I said, it's a guess, I'm not even sure if they use layers. It's just another avenue to poke around with and see if you see anything.

Comment: is the texture pack available to the game ? could be a path issue. you could disable lighting calculations altogether in the past, try to see what unchecking the "rad" pass does.

Comment: Try using the dev textures (the orange ones beginning with `dev/`), and in the game, using `mat_fullbright 1`. The dev textures work in any game automatically, and `mat_fullbright` causes lightmaps to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as well. I wanted to create a moving brush, but it turned black in my map. I tried turning  some light and shadow options on and off in the brush, but it changed nothing.

I solved it like this: in the field "Minimum light Level", put in a low mumber, such as 1.1. If it's still to dark, increase the number, and if it's to bright lower the number.

There is still just one problem. The hole brush is on 1 Light Level, so the Light Level on the brush is the same everywhere, and doesn't vary like on other textures, the more they are near a light Entity.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Doesn't look perfect, but at least it fixes part of the issue. You could cut the brush in to multiple ones, and set the Light Level on each of them. Hope this helps.

Comment: Presumably the moving object cannot have a lightmap because  the lighting changes as it moves and lightmaps don't.